# Query to get data from relational databases in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this database format below (taken from phpmyadmin, the tables are relational already):

[image: database]

I'm trying to get all "videos.Video_Name, videos.Video_URL" with a certain "tags.Tag_Name" via the "tagmap" relational mapping. I've never really used MySQL before for anything more than SELECT's and DELETE's and the syntax of JOIN is proving too much to bear, and at this point it'd just be faster to ask for help than to keep bashing my head against it.

I know I should be using JOIN but I have no idea of the syntax to accomplish what  I want.

The completely invalid query I tried was:

```
SELECT videos.Video_URL, videos.Video_Name
FROM tagmap
INNER JOIN videos ON videos.Video_ID = tagmap.Video_ID
INNER JOIN tagmap ON tagmap.Tag_ID = tags.Tag_ID
WHERE tags.Tag_Name = '$_GET[tag]'
```

But it returned no rows.

Comment: `$_GET[tag]` may be undefined may be a left join is required

Comment: Do all the tables have values? Also, **don't place raw variables in your query**! Your query is wide open to SQL Injection.

Comment: The `FROM` line should reference `tags` not `tagmap` also

Comment: Also there is a single quote in front of `'$_GET[tag]` but none after it. Also there are no quotes around 'tag' itself (`$_GET['tag']`). That might be it too. your query seems correct

Comment: @ArunKillu There's an "if (isset($_get[tag]))" beforehand, so it's not that. I honestly can't tell what type of join I need here

Comment: @BenM It's okay! this is for a completely personal use thing, I know all about SQL injection and the dangers. I'd never write something like this for a public site ahah.

Comment: @Twitch it can be empty string also as everyone says you are prone to sql injection

Comment: @Twitch You should *never* write code if you know it’s vulnerable, *ever*. Even if it’s a personal project. Maybe one day it won’t be, and you’ll forget all about the vulnerability until a hacker exposes. **Get into the habit or writing secure code**.

Comment: I do write secure code! But I'm not going to spend time escaping something that's not seen by anyone else. Also I'd never use php for a real project, so,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now Try this one.

```
SELECT videos.Video_Name, videos.Video_URL FROM videos,tags,tagmap
WHERE videos.Video_ID = tagmap.Video_ID AND tags.Tag_ID = tagmap.Tag_ID AND
tags.Tag_Name='$_GET[tag]'
```

Same Result with Joins

```
SELECT videos.Video_Name, videos.Video_URL FROM tagmap
RIGHT JOIN videos ON videos.Video_ID = tagmap.Video_ID 
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.Tag_ID = tagmap.Tag_ID 
WHERE tags.Tag_Name = '$_GET[tag]'
```

Hope it will not give any error.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Neither did mine. Or the JOIN LEFT suggestion. This is the result: http://i.imgur.com/71Efcrq.png from this snippet of code: http://i.imgur.com/DXYf3gw.png

Comment: Twitch, Now i have changed the query. Now please check again.

Comment: -1: this is functionally no different from the original query.

Comment: Hmh. This does work but is there a way to do it with JOIN? I'd assume that's what JOIN is for and would be faster. No problem though, I'll accept this answer until then.

Answer (score 0):

If your query returned no raws and did not a return an error then it's not "completely invalid".

Indeed, looking at the code, it should do exactly what you say you are trying to achieve. Hence if it's returning no rows then the reason must be that there is no matching data.

Break it down to find out where the data is missing:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tags
WHERE tags.Tag_Name = '$_GET[tag]';
```

If you get a non-zero value then try....

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tagmap.Video_ID), COUNT(*)
FROM tags INNER JOIN tagmp
ON tags.tag_ID=tagmap.tag_ID
WHERE tags.Tag_Name = '$_GET[tag]';
```

(BTW you might want to read up on SQL Injection).